# Определение метода одного класса в другом

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компоновщик

Есть шаблон класса Foo, который является частью библиотечного кода. В классе, помимо прочих, объявлен метод F2, который пользователь при желании может определять (сделано так, чтобы не тащить в рантайм лишние операции).

Этот же класс может быть использован как шаблонный аргумент для другого, пусть Foo2, тоже библиотечного, причем в этом случае в классе Foo2 заведомо известно, как должен работать метод F2 этого аргумента и хотелось бы его прямо тут определить (опционально - сделать дружественным). Но так нельзя. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как можно определить этот метод наиболее близким к желаемому способом?

Прикрепляю код и его же на [GODBOLT](https://godbolt.org/z/effooz8qY).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Библиотечный код.
// Класс может быть использован как самостоятельно,
// так и как шаблонный аргумент
template<auto A>
struct Foo {
    static void F1()
    {
        std::cout << A << std::endl;
    }

    static void F2();
};

// Тоже библиотечный код
template<auto A, typename B>
struct Foo2
{
    static void F1()
    {
        std::cout << A << std::endl;
    }

    // Хочу где-то здесь определить B::F2
};

using FooInstance = Foo<10>;
using Foo2Instance = Foo2<20, FooInstance>;

// Если инстанс Foo используется самостоятельно, то
// юзер может определить метод:
//template<>
//void FooInstance::F2()
//{
//    FooInstance::F1();
//}

int main()
{
    FooInstance::F1();
    Foo2Instance::F1();
    
//    FooInstance::F2();
}
```

Comment: Моежт лучьше пусть пользователь передает `Foo::F2` в качестве еще одного аргумента шаблона?

Comment: Так можно, конечно, но в идеальном случае пользователю здесь вообще не надо знать, что у `Foo` не определен метод и тем более подробности его реализации.

Comment: А зачем именно **в классе**? Вас же не смущает, например, что оператор типа вывода в поток `<<`, который, по сути, есть часть интерфейса класса,  вы объявляете вне класса? Откуда такая необходимость?

Comment: @Harry потому что это библиотечный код. В реальности `Foo` - это абстракция над таймером в микроконтроллере. Таймеры могут использоваться как самостоятельно, так и как вспомогательная часть какой-то логики. В данном случае я пытаюсь набросать драйвер RPC, которому таймер нужен для определения паузы между посылками (чтобы буфер сбросить). Концептуально пользователю всё равно, что должно происходить при истечении таймера (прерывании), он просто должен выделить под эту задачу один таймер (специализацию шаблона) и всё.

Comment: @Harry Вот кстати аналогия с оператором меня бы устроила, его же можно объявить внутри как дружественную функцию и тут же определить. По сути, в пределах, скажем так, фигурных скобок класса.

Comment: Т.е. пользователь эту специализацию не пишет вообще? Тогда какое ему дело, где именно вы ее напишете?...

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Вы никак не можете менять реализацию классов / специализировать - параметров шаблона (из другого шаблона).  Хотя бы по тому, что синтаксис допускает  использования одного и того же интсанса Foo в нескольких Foo2.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/GrWrM5P3z

Comment: @Harry да, не пишет. Для разных специализаций реализация может быть разной, а какую именно из них пользователь подсунет в качестве шаблонного аргумента  мы заранее не знаем.

Comment: @Chorkov спасибо за пример, примерно такое решение тоже прикидывал, оно наиболее близкое к тому, что я хочу, но самый нижний обработчик прерывания будет дергать метод именно базового класса. Видимо, стоит признать, что моя хотелка невозможна. Всем большое спасибо!